# Meaning of "canonicalizing data"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm, line 2.

> it is also often useful for **canonicalizing** data and for producing
>   human-readable output

what's the "canonicalizing data" ? Could you give me some examples?

Comment: If you click the word *canonicalizing* in that sentence (on the Wikipedia page), you will be brought to another Wikipedia page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization, which should answer your questions.

Comment: @DamkerngT. the article is too complicated for me. I just want some example, then maybe I could understand it.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the first paragraph on that Canonicalization page first. Then, you may look for some examples under sections "Web servers" and "XML" (you may skip all the text and check out only the examples, which are formatted as code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general definition of "canon" is the body of laws or rules of a church, or the set of documents accepted as authoritative in a religion. Something that conforms to the canon law is "canonical". For example, the accepted books of the Bible are called "the canon" (sometimes capitalized, "the Canon"), or "the canonical books".

The term "canonical" has been adopted in information technology to mean something that conforms to the rules of a programming language or a specification. So you might say that a properly formatted XML file is "in canonical XML form".

To take something that is not in canonical form and make it canonical form is to "canonicalize" it.